# Calculating precision, recall and FScore from the results of a confusion matrix in R

Tags: r, confusion-matrix, precision-recall

I have got th following confusion matrix, now I need to calculate the precision, recall and FScore from it, how do I do that using the obtained values?
    Confusion Matrix and Statistics

```
      Reference
Prediction One Zero
      One   37   43
      Zero  19  131

               Accuracy : 0.7304          
                 95% CI : (0.6682, 0.7866)
    No Information Rate : 0.7565          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.841087        

                  Kappa : 0.3611          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.003489        

            Sensitivity : 0.6607          
            Specificity : 0.7529          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.4625          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.8733          
             Prevalence : 0.2435          
         Detection Rate : 0.1609          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.3478          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7068          

       'Positive' Class : One
```

I've used the following edited code after suggestions from other users

```
library(class)
library(e1071)
library(caret)
library(party)
library(nnet)
library(forecast)
pimad <- read.csv("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/AMAN/pimad.csv")
nrow(pimad)  
set.seed(9850)
gp<-runif(nrow(pimad))
pimad<-pimad[order(gp),]
idx <- createDataPartition(y = pimad$class, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
train<-pimad[idx,]
test<-pimad[-idx,]
svmmodel<-svm(class~.,train,kernel="radial")
psvm<-predict(svmmodel,test)
table(psvm,test$class)
library(sos)
findFn("confusion matrix precision recall FScore")
df<-(confusionMatrix(test$class, psvm))
dim(df)
df[1,2]/sum(df[1,2:3])
df
```

Comment: This should help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix

Comment: `install.packages(sos); library(sos); findFn("confusion matrix precision recall FScore")`

Comment: @Pascal what does this do?

Comment: It searches function that could calculate what you are looking for. Something to do before asking here.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing else you need to do, you've got all the requested measures in df. Just type:

> ls(df)
>   [1] "byClass"  "dots"     "mode"     "overall"  "positive" "table"
>
> df$byClass # This is another example I've worked on

Now all the parameters including sensitivity, specificity, pos pred val, neg pred val, precision, recall, F1, prevalence, detection rate, detection prevalence and balanced accuracy appears in a table

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's simple calculation subsetting the matrix.

If your confusion matrix is called `df`, using the formulas [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score):

```
df
  Prediction One Zero
1        One  37   43
2       Zero  19  131

# Precision: tp/(tp+fp):
df[1,1]/sum(df[1,1:2])
[1] 0.4625

# Recall: tp/(tp + fn):
df[1,1]/sum(df[1:2,1])
[1] 0.6607143

# F-Score: 2 * precision * recall /(precision + recall):
2 * 0.4625 * 0.6607143 / (0.4625 + 0.6607143)
[1] 0.5441177
```

Comment: i changed the code to df<-(confusionMatrix(test$class, psvm))
  df[1,2]/sum(df[1,2:3])
  but the following error is generated : Error in df[1, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: How does your `df` look like? What says `dim(df)`?

Comment: dim(df) is returning NULL

Comment: You must somehow get your matrix saved as `df`.

Comment: I'va posted the code, if you could please review it and tell me regarding how to save the confusion matrix as a data frame

Comment: Do the following: `df <- confusionMatrix(df)$table`

Comment: the following error is generated : Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?

Comment: Thank you but I used nother method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
cm<-confusionMatrix(table(test_actual,test_predicted))
cm$byclass
cm$overall
```

NOTE 1: cm is confusionMatrix obtained by caret library of R

NOTE 2: cm$byclass gives: Sensitivity,Specificity,Pos Pred Value,Neg Pred Value, Precision, Recall,F1,Prevalence,Detection Rate Detection Prevalence Balanced Accuracy

NOTE 3: cm$overallgives Accuracy, Kappa, AccuracyLower, AccuracyUpper, AccuracyNull, AccuracyPValue